# C#.net winforms and usercontrol event handling

Tags: c#

I have a combobox and an usercontrol in mainWindowForm, how  can I update data in usercontrol on selectedIndexChange of comboBox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(UpdateUserControl);

public void UpdateUserControl(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Update UserControl data...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wire a SelectionChanged event of the combobox and update the data in the subsequent method that is generated.

For Example: UserCtrl1 ---has---> ComboBox1
Wire a selection changed event like

```
comboBox1.SelectionChanged += comboBox1_SelectionChanged;

public void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Update data on user control
}
```